# How to concat "$" special character with another field in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have aggregation pipeline where at the end of $project, I need to send dollar amount. I need to send as string that is concatenation of "$" and amount field. I am unable to use concat because "$" is a special character in Mongodb. Hope I can find an answer here.

The below mongo functionality does not work.

"$concat": [
          **"$",**
          {
            "$toString": "$Amount"
          }
        ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $literal

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { $addFields : { newAmount: { $concat: [ { $literal: "$"}, { $toString: "$Amount" } ] }} }
])
```

Comment: How come I miss about literal. Thank you so much